# Rails - dumping the database into a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I want to do is to dump the database into a custom created .rb file.

I found a seed_dump gem that allows me to do this:

```
rails db:seed:dump FILE=db/seeds/my_db_file_name.rb
```

Then I noticed that my datebase is our of order, so I found this on SO to include the ids:

```
rails db:seed:dump FILE=db/seeds/my_db_file_name.rb EXCLUDE=[]
```

Seemed fine until I wanted to add new record to my database. Turned out that reseting primary keys solved the problem:

```
def reset_pk
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
    end
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

What I am now want to do is to simplify the dumping process, as for now, every time I dump the data base the records are "out of order", what I will explain below.

Let's assume I have a two models: `Lab` and `Offer`. Lab can have many offers. So in order to create an `Offer` object I first have to create a `Lab` object. But when I dump the schema my file looks like this:

```
Offer.create...
Offer.create...
Offer.create

Lab.create...
Lab.create...
Lab.create...
```

and if I try to seed it, it won't do it as Offers are created before Labs, and it should be the other way.

My question is, is there a way to actually keep the relationships while dumping the database so Labs get created first?

**EDIT**

I managed to do something like this:

```
rails db:seed:dump FILE=db/seeds/my_db_file_name.rb EXCLUDE=[] MODELS="Lab, Offer"
```

This one keeps the order as I want it, but I wonder if there is a simple way (in case of having 15, 20 models instead of just 2).

Comment: Why do you want a Ruby file for this? Why don't you use your database's backup/dump tools?

Comment: I am rather new to rails and heroku stuff, and I want to have this database in a file in case I mess something up. I do use `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL databasename --app my_app_name` to get the db from heroku but as I said, just taking one more step to be sure that I do not delete all records.

Comment: So you're using `pg:pull` to copy the database to your local PostgreSQL? Why not use [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) to dump the local database?

Comment: @Ancinek You *already* have the database "in a file", in the best and most useable format you're going to get it in. Moving it into Ruby is a pointless exercise that makes your data *less* reliable and usable. There is no reason to do this.

Comment: Thanks guy for the answer. I think I will stop doing this because, as you said, there is no reason to do this. And I have a heroku backups just in case. Thanks anyway for to pg_dump option. Did not know about it!

Answer (score 0):

You could try dumping/restoring one table at a time in the order you wish.